# Android runtime error when adding imageview to view

Tags: java, android, xml, view, android-relativelayout

I'm having a runtime error when I'm adding an image to my main view/layout ( I tried with both ).

Code starts from an activity and I create the game board no problem, when it's done the game start, all this goes well.
The issue occurs when I press a button to add an image to the screen, I get a run time error at the moment the view is added into the main view.
In my code I'm keeping everything Java only, I'm avoiding XML files, I'm wondering if that might be a part of the problem.
I have been reading some solution to similar problem where people suggested to use the layout inflater method however I cannot find reference to a use of this method without having an XML file.

Here is my code

(PS sorry I see in the preview window how wierd it breaks at some moments... the error log is at the end

```
     RelativeLayout GameView = new RelativeLayout(this);
     GameView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
             screenHei,
             screenLen));




     //Start Game sequence
     ZoomView layout3 = new ZoomView(this);


     layout3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
             screenHei,
             screenLen));


     //Relative layout... aka base view that will be inserted in the zoom view
     RelativeLayout baseBoard = new RelativeLayout(this);
     //LinearLayOut Setup


     baseBoard.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
             screenHei,
             screenLen));


        LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);

        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 screenHei,
                 screenLen));
        //ImageView Setup
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        //setting image resource
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluepage);
        //setting image position

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 screenHei,
                 screenLen));
        //adding view to layout
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        linearLayout.addView(imageView);
        //make visible to program
        linearLayout.setX(0);
        linearLayout.setY(0);
//   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
//              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
//      lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, v.getId());

        baseBoard.addView(linearLayout); 
     layout3.setX(0);
     layout3.setY(0);



        final RelativeLayout menuMobile = new RelativeLayout(this);


         menuMobile.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 200,
                 200));
         menuMobile.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000 );

         Button ButtonMobile1 = new Button(this);
         ButtonMobile1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCCFFCC);
         ButtonMobile1.setText("test1");
         ButtonMobile1.setTextSize(6);
         ButtonMobile1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(155,66));
         ButtonMobile1.setX(100);
         ButtonMobile1.setY(40);
         menuMobile.addView(ButtonMobile1); 
         ButtonMobile1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                 Log.v("prepare to add barrack! "," testing Barrack ");
                 menuMobile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                ArrayList aList = (ArrayList) GroundWork.get(selectedX);
                 GameTile axs = (GameTile) aList.get(selectedY);

                   axs.selected=1;
                   axs.createBuilding(1,1,1);


                   addPicture(axs.imgSizeIds);


                   Log.v("tile selected value and information "," axs.selected :" + axs.selected);
                }
            });


     valueX=21;
     valueY=12;
     //Base map builder
     for(int l=0; l<=valueX; l++){
        dimension.clear() ;
        for (int w=0; w<=valueY; w++){


    // ArrayList<Button> dimension = new ArrayList<Button>();

     LinearLayout buttonLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
     buttonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     buttonLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                40,
                40));

     buttonLayout.setX(l*40);
     buttonLayout.setY(w*40);   

     System.out.println("Object Creation");
     final GameTile Tile = new GameTile();
     Tile.onCreate();
     Tile.pos_x=l;
     Tile.pos_y=w;
     System.out.println("Object                       !! CREATED !!");

     System.out.println("Object  added to prelim layout");

     Button b1 = new Button(this);
     b1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCCFFCC);
     b1.setText(" ");
     b1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(38,38));
     buttonLayout.addView(b1);
     baseBoard.addView(buttonLayout); 


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                 Log.v(Tile.button_hit,Tile.button_hit);
                // toggleMobileMenu();
                 menuMobile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 menuMobile.setX(Tile.pos_x*40);
                 menuMobile.setY(Tile.pos_y*40);

                 selectedX=Tile.pos_x;               
                 selectedY=Tile.pos_y;
                }
            });


        dimension.add(Tile); 


        }
        GroundWork.add(dimension); 
        System.out.println(" "+l);
     }
```

LinearLayout linearL= new LinearLayout(this);
linearL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

linearL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(                    40,             40));

linearL.setX(300);
 linearL.setY(340);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.castle);

```
       iv.setX(selectedX*40);
       iv.setY(selectedY*40);

        linearL.addView(iv); 

        player1img.add(iv); 

            linearL.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(40,40));

        baseBoard.addView(linearL);

//   setContentView(layout);
     Log.v("Added view to program", "Added view to program");

     imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000 );
     linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000 );
    layout3.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000 );

    int ACount;
    ACount = GroundWork.size();
    System.out.println("ACount");
    System.out.println(ACount);

    //Casting test
     //ArrayList<Button> checking = GroundWork.get(2);
    //Temp solution

        int BCount;
        BCount = dimension.size(); 
        System.out.println("BCount");
        System.out.println(BCount);

    //Adding final product to view  
         RelativeLayout menuView = new RelativeLayout(this);


         menuView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 screenHei,
                 150));
         menuView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000 );

         Button sendUnit = new Button(this);
         sendUnit.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCCFFCC);
         sendUnit.setText("test");
         sendUnit.setTextSize(8);
         sendUnit.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(155,66));
         sendUnit.setX(100);
         sendUnit.setY(40);
         menuView.addView(sendUnit); 
         sendUnit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                 Log.v(" test "," test ");
                 menuMobile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            });

        layout3.addView(baseBoard); 
        GameView.addView(layout3); 
        GameView.addView(menuView); 

        //Activating final View
        setContentView(GameView);


        GameView.addView(menuMobile); 


}

public void addPicture (int imgSizeIds) {



     LinearLayout linearL= new LinearLayout(this);
     linearL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     linearL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 40,
                 40));

     linearL.setX(selectedX*40);
     linearL.setY(selectedY*40);

    Log.v(" Adding Image in view and array ","   " + imgSizeIds);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

     Log.v(" Setting Image ","   " + imgSizeIds);
     iv.setImageResource(imgSizeIds);   
     iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.castle);
       Log.v("  Image assigned","   " + imgSizeIds);   
       iv.setX(selectedX*40);
       iv.setY(selectedY*40);

     Log.v(" Adding Image in layout  ","   " + imgSizeIds);
    linearL.addView(iv); 

      //  LayoutInflater popupLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        Log.v(" Adding layout in   Mainview ","   " + imgSizeIds);
        //linearL.showAtLocation(baseBoard, android.view.Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100, 100);
        //linearL = popupLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.baseBoard, null);

        linearL.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(40,40));


  //     RelativeLayout lL = findViewById(baseBoard);

   //           lL.addView(linearL);




        baseBoard.addView(linearL); 

         Log.v(" Adding in       array ","   " + imgSizeIds);
           player1img.add(iv); 

    Log.v(" COMPLETED  ","   " + imgSizeIds);
}
```

}

error Log

08-11 03:51:38.521: V/this_is_a_fucking_joke(768): this_is_a_fucking_joke
08-11 03:51:39.701: V/prepare to add barrack!(768):  testing Barrack 
08-11 03:51:39.711: V/CREATING building 1(768): CREATING building 1
08-11 03:51:39.711: V/CREATING building end of object(768): CREATING building end of object
08-11 03:51:39.711: V/Adding Image in view and array(768):    2130837505
08-11 03:51:39.711: V/Setting Image(768):    2130837505
08-11 03:51:39.711: V/Image assigned(768):    2130837505
08-11 03:51:39.721: V/Adding Image in layout(768):    2130837505
08-11 03:51:39.721: V/Adding layout in   Mainview(768):    2130837505
08-11 03:51:39.721: D/AndroidRuntime(768): Shutting down VM
08-11 03:51:39.721: W/dalvikvm(768): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.example.test2.GameBoard.addPicture(GameBoard.java:374)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.example.test2.GameBoard$1.onClick(GameBoard.java:169)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-11 03:51:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks alot for the help if anyone can see what wrong am I doing or not understanding.
is it a scope issue.
Am I using the right type of container...
I dont know :(

Thanks@

Comment: What line is: GameBoard.java:374 ?

Comment: You're hitting a null pointer exception on baseBoard. What method do you initialize baseBoard in?

Comment: Hi! thanks it's in the initialize, it's also declared before :   public class GameBoard extends Activity {                           View GameView;                                             @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                                          RelativeLayout baseBoard = new RelativeLayout(this);
     //LinearLayOut Setup


     baseBoard.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
             screenHei,
             screenLen));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're declaring baseBoard as a member variable but masking it with a local variable named baseBoard in your onCreate method (or wherever the first blob of code you posted came from).

Here's what I think is going on:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout baseBoard;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RelativeLayout baseBoard = new RelativeLayout(this);
    }
}
```

In this code, you declare two different variables called "baseBoard". The variable that is declared in your onCreate masks the member variable "baseBoard" and prevents it from ever getting set. That's why you hit a null pointer exception in your click handler.

Comment: Sorry to sound like a noob, I do I make sure I use the member variable . Do I just avoid to use RelativeLayout baseBoard = new RelativeLayout(this); that line?

Comment: When you include the type, it makes it a variable declaration. Remove the word "RelativeLayout" from the line in your onCreate method to change it from a local variable declaration to an ordinary member variable assignment.

Comment: that did it! that's great I think my knowledge of Java just got up a notch I think I didnt knew that before and it's strangely familiar as how we do it in Objective-C